# form validation using Jquery to check character length

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am attempting to use JQuery to count how many characters are in each input field.

Currently I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add_post_title').keyup(function(){

        var max = 25;
        var len = $(this).val().length;

        if(len > max){
            $('#check_title').text('No');
        }else{
            var char = max - len;
            $('#check_title').text('Yes');
        }

    });

    $('#add_post_desc').keyup(function(){

        var max = 25;
        var len = $(this).val().length;

        if(len > max){
            $('#check_desc').text('No');
        }else{
            var char = max - len;
            $('#check_desc').text('Yes');
        }

    });
});
```

And the html form (simplified a bit):

```
<form>
<div id="check_title"><p>No</p></div>  <div id="check_post"><p>No</p></div>
<input type="text" name="title" class="post_input" id="add_post_title" placeholder="Title" /><br />
<textarea name="desc" id="add_post_desc" placeholder="Description"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="add_post_submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Why is the text inside the "check" div's not changing to Yes when text is input into the fields?

Thanks

Comment: Please mark one of the answers below as correct if we have fixed your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using check_desc instead of check_post:

```
        $('#add_post_desc').keyup(function(){

    var max = 25;
    var len = $(this).val().length;

    if(len > max){
        $('#check_post').text('No');
    }else{
        var char = max - len;
        $('#check_post').text('Yes');
    }

});
```

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NxWnv/

Answer (score 1):

You code is almost fine. Except that that the check on the field `$('#add_post_desc')` is setting the div `check_desc` to yes instead of the div `check_post`.

Besides that it works fine. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KEBTQ/)